# Best way to update multiple fields of a Java object

Tags: java, builder

I want to update multiple fields of a Java object at once to perform a check on the update. My idea looks like this:

```
SomethingValues values = new SomethingValues();
values.name = "abc";
values.amount = 12;
values.weight = 42.2;
...
something.update(values);
```

An alternative would be a `SomethingValuesBuilder`, but I think that the additional code needed for a builder is not necessary here.

If I would use setters ...

```
something.setName("abc"); // would perform check
something.setAmount(12);  // would perform check
...
```

... I'd need to perform the check on each setter instead of only one time for all fields in the `update` method.

Is there any better idea than updating the domain object (`something`) with an additional value object (`values`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually go for the `SomeObjectType.update(parameters)` in which the object is responsible of checking and setting all parameters and eventually throw an `IllegalArgumentException` in case some of the parameters are not accepted. This way you acheive better readability and encapsulation.

Comment: I presume that you meant my first approach, which I'm actually using now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what's most commonly used is a `Map<String, Object>` because it doesn't require any extra classes.

Examples:

- [`Beanutils.populate(Object bean, Map properties)`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#line.430) from [commons / beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/)
- Spring's [`BeanWrapper`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans) technology also uses Maps and integrates validation

Comment: But then you have to look up field names reflectively and cast object to the required type. Both is not so good for refactoring.

Comment: @deamon true, but neither is a custom Object, unless your main Object inherits from it

Comment: You could instead use a `Map<SomethingValuesFieldsEnum,Object>`, which gives a bit more protection. (Think: `Calendar.set()`)

Comment: @BRPocock yes, but that would tie the technology to a particular set of classes

Comment: d'oh. I was actually thinking of that as a benefit (using the enum to help identify needed fields for a transaction), but definitely a different direction of going than e.g. Beanutils.

Comment: @BRPocock the thing is: it will make working with one class easier, but it will make reusing code for different unrelated classes a lot more difficult

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;

BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: this is allow to exclude some properties: ```BeanUtils.copyProperties(newUserData, appUser, "id", "roles")```